# Why is the option to create a new site in IIS not enabled in the New Web Site dialog in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Professional as Administrator on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with IIS installed and Application Pools configured to use Framework v4.0 by default.

When adding a Web Site project to a blank solution and choosing Local IIS in the Choose Location dialog, the option for New Site (small icon top right) is not available. other options are available but those only create a new virtual dir or web app in an existing web site.

[image: Screenshot VS IIS]

Why would that option be disabled?